# Prevent App Engine from logging client file requests

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on an App Engine project in java. I have an index.html and some .js and .css files in the war directory. Everytime the files in the war directory are accessed, it is logged. So I have tons of log entries which are just saying these files were accessed, but the only thing I'm interested in is the calls to my API. Is there a way I can turn off logging of these client side files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Request logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/) are a service provided by the platform. You have no control over what requests get logged, you can only control the maximum size of all logs and the max age of log records (on the Application Settings page of the Admin Console).

Actually, all requests get logged - even the cron and task queue requests. What you can do is filter the displayed logs or the queried records if you use the Logs API. The full list of log properties can be viewed [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/RequestLogs).

There are log properties based on which you can tell if the request was targeted a static resource file, e.g. the `instance` on the log page or [`RequestLogs.getInstanceKey()`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/log/RequestLogs#getInstanceKey()) in the API. Static file contents are not served by the instances of your application but by dedicated Google servers so in these cases there is no instance key while requests served by `Servlet`s for example will have an instance key.